# What function implements density / quantile functions for the Raised cosine distribution in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking for the equivalents of `qnorm` and `dnorm` for the [raised cosine distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_cosine_distribution) in R

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
drcosd <- function(x,mu, s) { (1/2*s)*(1+cos( pi*(x-mu)/s )) }
```

The creation of a `prcosd` would seem to be just as straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Correction. That would be

```
drcosd <- function(x,mu,s) { 1/(2*s)*(1+cos(pi*(x-mu)/s)) }
```

NB Divide by s in segment 1/(2*s) not multiply.

In fact, the distribution is defined as negative outside of [mu-s,mu+s] so more formally this should be

```
drcosd <- function(x,mu,s) { 
          d <-ifelse(abs(x-mu)<=s,1/(2*s)*(1+cos(pi*(x-mu)/s)),0) 
          d 
          }
```